# How to "convert" a dequed object to string in Python?

Tags: python, collections, rotation, deque

I am trying to output a rotated version of a string. I have taken a string, `z="string"`, and created a deque out of it, `y=collections.deque(z) (deque(['S','t','r','i','n','g'])`, and rotated it using the rotate method. How do I "convert" that deque object I rotated back to a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer to your question: Since a deque is a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), you can generally use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to form a string from the ordered elements of that collection. `str.join` works more broadly on any Python [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) to form a string from the elements joined together one by one.

BUT, suggestion, instead of a deque and rotate and join, you can also concatenate slices on the string itself to form a new string:

```
>>> z="string"
>>> rot=3
>>> z[rot:]+z[:rot]
'ingstr'
```

Which works both ways:

```
>>> rz=z[rot:]+z[:rot]
>>> rz
'ingstr'
>>> rz[-rot:]+rz[:-rot]
'string'
```

Besides being easier to read (IMHO) It also turns out to be **a whole lot faster:**

```
from __future__ import print_function  #same code for Py2 Py3
import timeit
import collections

z='string'*10
def f1(tgt,rot=3):
    return tgt[rot:]+tgt[:rot]

def f2(tgt,rot=3):
    y=collections.deque(tgt)
    y.rotate(rot)
    return ''.join(y)

print(f1(z)==f2(z))    # Make sure they produce the same result
t1=timeit.timeit("f1(z)", setup="from __main__ import f1,z")
t2=timeit.timeit("f2(z)", setup="from __main__ import f2,z")    
print('f1: {:.2f} secs\nf2: {:.2f} secs\n faster is {:.2f}% faster.\n'.format(
           t1,t2,(max(t1,t2)/min(t1,t2)-1)*100.0))
```

Prints:

```
True
f1: 0.32 secs
f2: 5.02 secs
 faster is 1474.49% faster.
```

Comment: Using slice here is faster because create deque use too much time.

Answer (score 6):

Just use [str.`join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
>>> y.rotate(3)
>>> y
deque(['i', 'n', 'g', 's', 't', 'r'])
>>> 
>>> ''.join(y)
'ingstr'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just concatenate the characters in the string:

```
''.join(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `join()`:

```
''.join(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [string join method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
''.join(y)
```

---

```
In [44]: import collections
In [45]: z = "string"
In [46]: y = collections.deque(z)
In [47]: ''.join(y) 
Out[47]: 'string'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `''.join(y)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use the `join` method on the string.

```
''.join(y)
```